# Merging different tiff files to a single multiband image in python

Tags: python, raster

Presently I am using rasterio for writing datasets.
how can we merge tiff files containing different band data into a single multiband image (3D raster)

I tried using one of the sample raster file (similar to the band tiff file) and modified its profile and rewriting data using rasterio. the code roughly looks as follows

```
with rasterio.open(
    "C:/shrey/bits pilani/anant/payload/basler_img/to_combine/test_imgZ1.tiff",
    'w+',
     #other neccesary information including count)as src:
    src.write(< a 3 d array>)
```